# Classical fermions, where are they?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, fermions, classical-field-theory, grassmann-numbers

**Context:**

Studying the path integral formulation of QFT I stumbled upon a fairly simple statement: when doing loop expansions of a partition function:

$$Z[\eta ; \bar{\eta}] = \int [d\psi][d\bar{\psi}]e^{-S_E[\psi, \bar{\psi}] + \bar{\eta}\psi + \eta\bar{\psi}}.$$

You search for a stationary point and the field which satisfy that is called the classical field, so you can expand:

$$\psi (x) = \psi_{cl}(x) + \chi(x).$$

All good with that.

Then I started thinking about what they means and realised that classical fermion fields doesn't exist. Deeply no classical field exist, but we still observe phenomena described by vector/scalar fields in the classical world, while we do not observe classical phenomena described by fermionic fields in the classical domain. This made me think of the following mental problem.

**The thought experiment:**

Suppose you are a physicist from another world. You know nothing about quantum mechanics, for your civilation such a thing does not exist.
You do know about special relativity and the necessary group/representation theory.
Working with the Lorentz group you discovered that you can break down the algebra into two $\mathcal{su}(2)$ component and you label a representation with $(a, b)$ where $a,b$ are half integers.

You seem satisfied, you see a $(0,0)$ component which describes a scalar field.

You see the $(1/2 , 1/2)$ four vectors and that's cool.

You see $(1,1)$ tensors such as the energy momentum tensor.

You see $(1,0)\oplus (0,1)$ and given that you know classical electromagnetism you are happy that this also is included into your theory.

Then the problem: your theory tells you that $(1/2 , 0)$ and $(0, 1/2)$ fields should appear when you look at the sky or into your lab, but there is no trace of such fields.

Why your theory predicts such fields at a classical level, but you don't see them? Is it a detection problem or such fields are just forbidden due to some inconsistency with some classical principle?

I'm trying to understand if there is even an explanation which doesn't involve QM and the Pauli principle, so if there are classical reasons that forbid such a field to exist classically.

**Disclaimer:**

I already know the QM motivation: you can't have the same wave function numbers between fermions so you can't have a huge number of identical one like you do for photons in EM waves. You can't make classical fermion waves due to QM.

Comment: This question seems upside-down to me. You can define a [Grassman-valued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number) classical fermion field without any trouble. Classical fermion fields aren't observed in nature, but neither are classical boson fields - nature is, as far as we know, purely quantum mechanical. In that sense, your question becomes why the *quantum* bosonic fields we observe (sometimes) behave like *classical* boson fields do, but then you already answer that question with your disclaimer.

Comment: Yes, i know the quantum side, but the question fundamentally is: since classical special relativity predicts classical Weyl fields, why such entities are not here, from a purely classical POV? If there is no reason in the classical theory to justify the lack of them, that is still a good answer. The classical theory is broken also counts, in the mood of the question this could be a reason for the fantasy-physicists to search for deeper theories, if needed

Comment: So your question is: since classical special relativity predicts classical Weyl fields (a point which I'd dispute, but never mind that now), why do such entities not appear in a universe **which is not governed by classical special relativity**? I think there's a reasonable question here about the nature of classical fermion fields, but asking why **we** don't observe them is missing the larger point that we don't observe classical *boson* fields either.

Comment: Why do you say that a classical boson field doesn't exist? By boson i mean an integer spin field

Comment: From the perspective of elementary particle physics, there simply are no classical fields. Which classical boson fields do you have in mind?

Comment: Yes i know, but my question is from the perspective of classical physics, not quantum physics. Take a scalar field of your choice. That's a classical spin 0 field.  Without taking into account QED, we have the classical EM field which is a spin 1, and so on. Forgetting the particle physics/QM stuff, is it possible to justify the absence of classical half integer spin fields without changing framework? Or is it justifiable only through other theories, like in fact QM?

Comment: You continue to miss my point, I think. You are trying to justify the absence of classical fermionic fields **from a quantum universe**. If you ask about the *absence* of something, you're talking about a place where you *expect* to see it but don't.  But the place you're talking about is *our universe*, which is **quantum** by nature. We **don't** have a classical EM field - we have a *quantum* EM field which, under a certain range of circumstances, behaves like a classical EM field would behave.

Comment: I think what you're trying to ask is whether or not there is some fundamental reason - an inconsistency, or some kind of no-go theorem, or some deep physical principle - why a classical fermionic field cannot exist. That is a fine question. But then you frame it in terms of observations that *we* - the inhabitants in a quantum universe - are making, and then the answer to "why don't we see classical fermionic fields" is the same as the answer to "why don't we see classical bosonic fields" - namely, that there are no classical fields *at all*.

Comment: Yes, my point is exactly whether or not there is some fundamental reason like an inconsistency in SR, or some kind of no-go theorem etc why a classical fermionic field cannot exist. By "we observe" this is what i meant, if RS contains a no go theorem on classical half integers spin. If it is just due to our universe being quantum and RS alone doesn't suffice, then that is a good answer too.

Comment: If that's the case, then I would suggest removing "Then I started thinking about what they means and realised that classical fermion fields doesn't exist" from your question, because that entire line of reasoning is predicated on the observations that you're making *in a quantum universe*. The reason observers in our universe don't see classical fields is because our universe is not classical, which is a fairly dull observation. The deeper question is not why **we** don't see classical fermionic fields, but whether they are in some way incompatible with the rest of classical physics.

Comment: I will state it more clearly then, let me edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Working with the Lorentz group you discovered that you can break down the algebra into two $su(2)$ component and you label a representation with (,) where , are half integers.

Be a bit more careful here. There are two objects at play: the Lorentz group $SO(1,3),$ and the Lie algebra of the Lorentz group, $\mathfrak{so}(1,3).$ The irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ are labelled by distinct pairs of nonnegative half-integers, and every pair of nonnegative half-integers corresponds to a representation. The representations of $SO(1,3)$ all correspond to representations of $\mathfrak{so}(1,3),$ *but not the other way around*. There are representations of $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ that do not ascend to representations of $SO(1,3).$ A representation of $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ is "local" data (around the identity transformation). It does not necessarily extend to the whole group, especially since $SO(1,3)$ is not simply connected. In particular, the $(m,n)$ irrep of $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ only gives rise to a representation of the Lorentz group if $m+n$ is an integer.

This should be obvious in hindsight: we often say a spinor picks up a minus sign under a $2\pi$ rotation, instead of returning to itself. This clearly contradicts the idea of a representation of $SO(1,3),$ since a $2\pi$ rotation is supposed to do nothing!

So, to a classical physicist, spinors don't exist. There's a hint of them, since $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ has the half-spin representations, but the classical physicist thinks they're just mathematical artifacts. The physical object is $SO(1,3),$ and it lacks the spinor representations. To reiterate: spinors do not actually carry a representation of the Lorentz group. That's why your alternate universe classical physicist doesn't expect to see them, and why there is no field in our universe that seems to approximate a "classical spinor field". (Once more to hammer it in: rotating your measurement system one full turn *shouldn't be able* to make real objects reverse direction!)

In quantum mechanics, you have the additional freedom that states are equivalent up to phase. Picking up a minus sign no longer changes the physical state of a spinor. For a spinor field $\psi,$ replacing the field with its negative $\psi\mapsto-\psi$ doesn't change any observable quantity. With this in mind, "what are representations of the Lorentz group?" is now the wrong question. You don't need to demand a representation of $SO(1,3)$ to have a coherent theory anymore. A quantum theory only needs a (unitary) "projective representation" of $SO(1,3)$ in order to be relativistic. The transformation has freedom to muck with the unobservable complex phase in a way that isn't possible in a classical theory, where you expect to be able to observe every quantity.

The earlier obstruction to spinors, where we noted that the spinor representations of $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ fail to extend to representations of $SO(1,3),$ can now be bypassed. The spinor representations *do* extend to projective representations of $SO(1,3).$ So: only once you've allowed the world to be quantum do you allow spinors to exist. (Since the world happens to be quantum, the idea of a strict representation of $SO(1,3)$ is not too important to physicists, so they say "representation" but mean "projective representation". Hence your confusion.)

The upshot of this is that while we can have Lorentz-covariant classical field theories involving scalar fields, vector fields (particularly electromagnetism), 2-tensor fields (particularly gravity), etc., we can't have spinor fields. You can, of course, write down e.g. the Dirac equation and treat $\psi$ as being made up of numbers and not observables, thus making a classical theory of a spinor field. But you either have to give up on all the components of $\psi$ being observable (so some part of classicality) or on Lorentz-covariance (which demands the minus sign on a single turn be unobservable).

Comment: "So, to a classical physicist, spinors don't exist." That is not entirely true. Under appropriate conditions the polarization of light is represented by the spin-half representation of SU(2), leading to the Poincare sphere, which is formally equivalent to the Bloch sphere.

Comment: This answer totally missed the point, as commented by @J. Murray, the classical fermion field is neither less nor more realistic than a classical boson field. You don't need quantization to justify the mathematical self-consistency of a classical spinor field. On the other hand, for the description of real world, you do need quantization of BOTH boson field and spinor field.